# Drop Shadow Showing Incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, layer, shadow

I am using a drop shadow in Swift. When I show it the first time the shadow is very harsh. When I redraw the view `selectedObstacle` it shows correctly. Is this a glitch or something?

```
selectedObstacle?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5)
selectedObstacle?.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
selectedObstacle?.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
selectedObstacle?.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What do you mean redraw?

Comment: Where do you add your shadow?, I had a similar problem and solved it by applying the shadow in viwDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: try setting shouldRasterize = false it may affect the performance but that should solve your problem

Comment: Nothing works. I tried to apply within viewDidLayoutSubviews and set shouldRasterize = false. Both did not work. When I redraw selectedObstacle.setNeedsDisplay() it changes the shadow to the correct settings.

Comment: same thing happens to me once, on my case I forgot to put the code on the main thread